# Handling error with Promise

Tags: error-handling, asynchronous-programming

I'm writing a small application in TypeScript that has to do some asynchronous operation and I'm doing it with `Promise` and `async/await` sugar. But my problem do not rely on the particular language or asynchronicity strategy.

The operation are both I/O and network operation, something like:

- every 2 minutes find a suitable file from the file system
- calculate sha1
- stream it via tcp
- wait for the response and check if the received sha1 is ok

I don't know when and how handle errors: normally I have to log the error into the db and continue the next iteration or do a retry.

But when to log? when to use the catch?

The first idea is at top level:

```
const result = await doEverything().catch( function(err) {
    if(err.code === 'file not found') ...
    if(err.code === 'connection timeout after 3 retry') ...
}
```

But I don't know if it is the best option. Can you advice me some good readings about best practice to handle errors?

Comment: It sounds like you already have your answer for this particular case: You *have* to keep going, so you have to catch the error, and only you know if there's something useful you can do with it beyond simply logging it. Is there something else you're not sure about in this example? Book recommendations are off-topic here, and describing every scenario where this may or may not be ideal is far too broad.

Comment: This depends on what you want to log. Apparently there's no way to log and handle a remote error until you have done executing the (async) call to the remote endpoint. In the async case, you can (and likely will) have several invocations underway, sometimes completing out of order. Instead of "next iteration" you'll have a pool of operations in flight (it may be a good idea to somehow limit it). Nothing prevents you from logging the _beginning_ of the operation earlier, if you need it; you'll have some visibility into what operations are ion flight.